# Makefile that rebuilds on an external condition such as an ENV change

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to rebuild a program if an external condition has changed.

From this example, the condition is the date of the day and here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRINGIZE(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE_VALUE_OF(x) STRINGIZE(x)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%s", STRINGIZE_VALUE_OF(condition));
}
```

And the `Makefile`:

```
condition != date +"%m-%d-%y"
all: foo

foo: foo.c
   gcc -Dcondition="$(condition)" $< -o $@
```

I tried to modify the Makefile as follow:

```
condition != date +"%m-%d-%y" | perl -pe chomp

$(shell \
    if [ ! -f CONDITION] || [ "$(condition)" != "$$(cat CONDITION | perl -pe chomp)" ]; \
    then \
    echo "$(condition)" > CONDITION; \
    fi \
)   

all: foo

foo: foo.c | CONDITION
   gcc -Dcondition="$(condition)" $< -o $@
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. I guess because `make` evaluates if the files have changes right before executing my `$(shell)` routine.

How can I implement such feature with `make`?

**EDIT** 
The trick is to not call a sub-makefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to do here is **not** to *fight* make but to **use** it.

```
condition != date +"%m-%d-%y"

all: foo

foo: foo.c CONDITION
        gcc -Dcondition="$(condition)" $< -o $@

CONDITION: FORCE
        [ -f $@ ] && [ "$(condition)" = "$$(cat $@)" ] || echo '$(condition)' > $@

FORCE: ;
```

Comment: Oh, hah. That's just a default target issue. Move `all: foo` above `CONDITION`. Editing.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to turn you condition into a file timestamp and then make your target depend on that condition file.

Whenever the condition evaluates to `true` the condition file gets assigned a new timestamp causing a rebuild of all targets that depend on it. Changing the timestamp of that file must be made by `$(shell)` command.

E.g.

```
$ cat Makefile
# Example: update the condition every minute.
$(shell date +%Y%m%d%H%M > condition.txt.tmp; cmp --quiet condition.txt.tmp condition.txt 2>/dev/null || mv -f condition.txt.tmp condition.txt)

all : foo

foo : condition.txt
    @echo "rebuild $@ because $? changed."
    touch $@

$ date; make
Mon 18 Apr 15:17:25 BST 2016
rebuild foo because condition.txt changed.
touch foo
$ date; make
Mon 18 Apr 15:17:27 BST 2016
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
$ date; make
Mon 18 Apr 15:18:01 BST 2016
rebuild foo because condition.txt changed.
touch foo
$ date; make
Mon 18 Apr 15:18:03 BST 2016
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Comment: How does this differ from what the OP tried originally? Is it just that the OP tried an order-only prereq?

Answer (score 0):

I thing I found something. The trick is to mark the target as `.PHONY` if the condition is true

```
condition != date +"%m-%d-%y" | perl -pe chomp

need_rebuild != \
    if [ ! -f CONDITION ] || [ "$(condition)" != "$$(cat CONDITION | perl -pe chomp)" ]; \
    then \
    echo "$(condition)" > CONDITION; \
    echo YES; \
    fi

ifeq ($(need_rebuild),YES)
    $(info Rebuild Needed)
    .PHONY: foo
endif

all: foo

foo: foo.c | CONDITION
    gcc -Dcondition="$(condition)" $< -o $@
```

Comment: `.PHONY` may work for this but isn't the right solution. Use a temporary file as a condition "stamp" file that you only `touch` when `CONDITION` needs to be updated and it should do what you want.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is still the same, by the time you `touch` your `stamp` file, `make` has already determined if `stamp` is up-to-date or not

Comment: No, not if you use the normal make processes instead of working around them with games.